# Confusion about rolling motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, terminology

why is rolling motion translational? Isn't translational motion a motion where a body moves without changing its orientation?But in rolling motion,the object is rotating i.e changing its orientation every time. So why is it called rolling motion and translational motion combined?

Comment: In rolling motion the center mass is in translational motion

Comment: but in translational motion shouldn't every points of the body be in translational motion?

Comment: Rolling motion is a combination of rotational and translational motion

Comment: Oh,I get it now.Thank you

Comment: ...combination of rotational and translational motion, but _some_ problems can be solved without regard for the rolling component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a diagram of a body rolling at an angular speed $\omega$ and not slipping relative to the surface.

[image]

Note that every particle, including the one at the centre of mass, has a translational speed of $v$ but also a speed of $r\omega$ due to the rotational motion.

To get the velocity of a particle (blue arrows) one needs to add the velocity due to translation (red arrows) and the velocity due to rotation about the centre of mass (grey arrows).

Comment: How does every particle have a translational motion of speed v?Isn't translational motion a motion where the body moves without changing its orientation?

Comment: You have missed my point.  You can think of every particle having a translational velocity component and a rotational velocity component which when added together gives the actual instantaneous velocity of a particle.